# waitgroup on subset of go routines

Tags: multithreading, go, synchronization

I have situation where in, the main go routines will create "x" go routines. but it is interested only in "y" ( y < x ) go routines to finish.

I was hoping to use Waitgroup. But Waitgroup only allows me to wait on all go routines. I cannot, for example do this,

```
1. wg.Add (y)
2 create "x" go routines. These routines will call wg.Done() when finished. 
3. wg. Wait()
```

This panics when the y+1 go routine calls wg.Done() because the wg counter goes negative.

I sure can use channels to solve this but I am interested if Waitgroup solves this.

Comment: Is the number of goroutines, `y`, which the main flow of execution should wait on, fixed, or is it dynamically determined by a computed result?

Answer (score 5):

As noted in [Adrian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52227997/1113760), `sync.WaitGroup` is a simple counter whose `Wait` method will block until the counter value reaches zero. It is intended to allow you to block (or join) on a number of goroutines before allowing a main flow of execution to proceed.

The interface of `WaitGroup` is not sufficiently expressive for your usecase, nor is it designed to be. In particular, you cannot use it naïvely by simply calling `wg.Add(y)` (where y < x). The call to `wg.Done` by the (y+1)<sup>th</sup> goroutine will [cause a panic](https://play.golang.org/p/jVTHpUx9SrD), as it is an error for a wait group to have a negative internal value. Furthermore, we cannot be "smart" by observing the internal counter value of the `WaitGroup`; this would break an abstraction and, in any event, its internal state is not exported.

---

## Implement your own!

You can implement the relevant logic yourself using some channels per the code below ([playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/EpmZ9JFkZbQ)). Observe from the console that 10 goroutines are started, but after two have completed, we fallthrough to continue execution in the main method.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

// Set goroutine counts here
const (
    // The number of goroutines to spawn
    x = 10
    // The number of goroutines to wait for completion
    // (y <= x) must hold.
    y = 2
)

func doSomeWork() {
    // do something meaningful
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}

func main() {
    // Accumulator channel, used by each goroutine to signal completion.
    // It is buffered to ensure the [y+1, ..., x) goroutines do not block
    // when sending to the channel, which would cause a leak. It will be
    // garbage collected when all goroutines end and the channel falls
    // out of scope. We receive y values, so only need capacity to receive
    // (x-y) remaining values.
    accChan := make(chan struct{}, x-y)

    // Spawn "x" goroutines
    for i := 0; i < x; i += 1 {
        // Wrap our work function with the local signalling logic
        go func(id int, doneChan chan<- struct{}) {
            fmt.Printf("starting goroutine #%d\n", id)
            doSomeWork()
            fmt.Printf("goroutine #%d completed\n", id)

            // Communicate completion of goroutine
            doneChan <- struct{}{}
        }(i, accChan)
    }

    for doneCount := 0; doneCount < y; doneCount += 1 {
        <-accChan
    }

    // Continue working
    fmt.Println("Carrying on without waiting for more goroutines")
}
```

---

### Avoid leaking resources

As this does not wait for the [y+1, ..., x) goroutines to complete, you should take special care in the `doSomeWork` function to remove or minimize the risk that the work can block indefinitely, which would also cause a leak. Remove, where possible, the feasibility of indefinite blocking on I/O (including channel operations) or falling into infinite loops.

You could use a [`context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) to signal to the additional goroutines when their results are no longer required to have them break out of execution.

Answer (score 2):

`WaitGroup` doesn't actually wait on goroutines, it waits until its internal counter reaches zero. If you only `Add()` the number of goroutines you care about, and you only call `Done()` in those goroutines you care about, then `Wait()` will only block until those goroutines you care about have finished. You are in complete control of the logic and flow, there are no restrictions on what `WaitGroup` "allows".

Comment: Right. But, I dont know, apriori, which of the "y" go routines I care about. Quite simply, of the "x" go routines, I only want to wait for the first "y" routines that finish, not specific ones. Dont care about the remaining x-y go routines.

Answer (score 1):

Are these y specific go-routines that you are trying to track, or any y out of the x? What are the criteria?

Update:

**1. If you hve control over any criteria to pick `matching y` go-routines:**

You can do `wp.wg.Add(1)` and `wp.wg.Done()` from inside the goroutine based on your condition by passing it as a pointer argument into the goroutine, if your condition can't be checked outside the goroutine.

Something like below sample code. Will be able to be more specific if you provide more details of what you are trying to do.

```
func sampleGoroutine(z int, b string, wg *sync.WaitGroup){

    defer func(){
        if contition1{
            wg.Done()
        }
    }

    if contition1 {
        wg.Add(1)
        //do stuff
    }
}

func main() {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i := 0; i < x; i++ {
        go sampleGoroutine(1, "one", &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

**2. If you have no control over which ones, and just want the `first y`:**

Based on your comment, that you have no control/desire to pick any specific goroutines, but the ones that finish first. If you would want to do it in a generic way, you can use the below custom waitGroup implementation that fits your use case. (It's not copy-safe, though. Also doesn't have/need wg.Add(int) method)

```
type CountedWait struct {
    wait  chan struct{}
    limit int
}

func NewCountedWait(limit int) *CountedWait {
    return &CountedWait{
        wait:  make(chan struct{}, limit),
        limit: limit,
    }
}

func (cwg *CountedWait) Done() {
    cwg.wait <- struct{}{}
}

func (cwg *CountedWait) Wait() {
    count := 0
    for count < cwg.limit {
        <-cwg.wait
        count += 1
    }
}
```

Which can be used as follows:

```
func sampleGoroutine(z int, b string, wg *CountedWait) {

    success := false

    defer func() {
        if success == true {
            fmt.Printf("goroutine %d finished successfully\n", z)
            wg.Done()
        }
    }()

    fmt.Printf("goroutine %d started\n", z)
    time.Sleep(time.Second)

    if rand.Intn(10)%2 == 0 {
        success = true
    }
}

func main() {
    x := 10
    y := 3
    wg := NewCountedWait(y)

    for i := 0; i < x; i += 1 {
        // Wrap our work function with the local signalling logic
        go sampleGoroutine(i, "something", wg)
    }

    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Printf("%d out of %d goroutines finished successfully.\n", y, x)
}
```

**3. You can also club in `context` with 2 to ensure that the remaining goroutines don't leak**
You may not be able to run this on play.golang, as it has some long sleeps.

Below is a sample output:
(note that, there may be more than y=3 goroutines marking Done, but you are only waiting till 3 finish)

`goroutine 9 started
goroutine 0 started
goroutine 1 started
goroutine 2 started
goroutine 3 started
goroutine 4 started
goroutine 5 started
goroutine 5 marking done
goroutine 6 started
goroutine 7 started
goroutine 7 marking done
goroutine 8 started
goroutine 3 marking done
continuing after 3 out of 10 goroutines finished successfully.
goroutine 9 will be killed, bcz cancel
goroutine 8 will be killed, bcz cancel
goroutine 6 will be killed, bcz cancel
goroutine 1 will be killed, bcz cancel
goroutine 0 will be killed, bcz cancel
goroutine 4 will be killed, bcz cancel
goroutine 2 will be killed, bcz cancel`

Play links

1. https://play.golang.org/p/l5i6X3GClBq
2. https://play.golang.org/p/Bcns0l9OdFg
3. https://play.golang.org/p/rkGSLyclgje

Comment: Any "y" out of "x". Think of this as a race of "x" go routines. I am only interested in the top "y" finishers.

Comment: Updated the answer. Does it help now?